# What items provide shadow power or benefit from it?

Tags: tales-of-maj-eyal

I have found several demonologist themed items, such as The Black Core, The Black Wall, or The Black Plate which provide a stat called shadow power, and provide various benefits based on how much you have.

What items provide/benefit from shadow power, and what are the effects they possess that depends on it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking on the [wiki](http://te4.org/wiki/Item_set), it seems that all the items providing Shadow Power buffs are part of the Obsidian Treasures. Here is the list of the items of this set and their effects:

- [The Black Boots](http://te4.org/wiki/The_Black_Boots): +5 Shadow Power. Increases movement speed by 2.5% per Shadow Power.
- [The Black Core](http://te4.org/wiki/The_Black_Core) (Amulet): +5 Shadow Power. Grants spellpower equal to Shadow Power.
- [The Black Crown](http://te4.org/wiki/The_Black_Crown): +5 Shadow Power. Increases all saves equal to Shadow Power.
- [The Black Spike](http://te4.org/wiki/The_Black_Spike) (1 hand): +5 Shadow Power. Increases all damage penetration by 1% per Shadow Power.
- [The Black Maul](http://te4.org/wiki/The_Black_Maul) (2 hands): +10 Shadow Power. Increases all damage by 1% per Shadow Power.
- [The Black Plate](http://te4.org/wiki/The_Black_Plate): +10 Shadow Power. Increases physical power equal to Shadow Power.
- [The Black Ring](http://te4.org/wiki/The_Black_Ring): +5 Shadow Power. Grants spell-crit equal to half of your Shadow Power.
- [The Black Wall](http://te4.org/wiki/The_Black_Wall) (Shield): +5 Shadow Power. Increases all resist by 0.4% per Shadow Power.

Possessing the full set would award you with:

- +100 % movement speed.
- +40 spellpower.
- +40 to all saves.
- +40% damage penetration
- +40 Physical power
- +20 % spell-crit chance
- +16% to all resist.